# Run linq-to-sql queries on database with changing structure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

1. Is it possible to run Linq-to-SQL queries when underling database structure is changing from time to time (I mean database updates that happens due to business requirements and since database is shared among several apps It may be happens without announcements to me)?
2. Is there any way that I can connect to new database structure in Linq-to-SQL without updating the `.dbml` file in my source code?
3. If I want to run raw queries knowing that my database structure changes during time, can I use any of Linq-to-SQL benefits somehow?

Comment: You should have a property VERSION of database and the use the Version so code is backward compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the structure you have in your classes match to your tables (at least covering all the fields you need) you can do that. ie: Northwind customers table have more than 4 fields in reality. Provided below 4 are still in that table this would work:

```
void Main()
{
  DataContext db = new DataContext(@"server=.\SQLexpress;trusted_connection=yes;database=Northwind");
  Table<Customer> Customers = db.GetTable<Customer>();


  var data = Customers.Where(c => c.Country == "USA");
  foreach (var customer in data)
{
        Console.WriteLine($"{customer.CustomerID}, {customer.CompanyName}");
}
}

[Table(Name = "Customers")]
public class Customer
{
    [Column]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string ContactName { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string Country { get; set; }
}
```

For raw SQL, again you could use a type covering fields in select list or dynamic.

Note: For inserts, for this to work, fields that are not in your model should either accept null or have default values.